# PHP Notice: Undefined index: step on line 24 Call Stack

Tags: php, mysql

When i typed it, this error came out. I want to know why this error happens and how can i fix it. Thank you in advanced.

```
<html>
<meta charset=utf-8" />
<?php
$dbhandle = @mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
if($sql_banco= mysql_select_db('centroexames',$dbhandle)) {
    echo "Ligação bem sucedida". "<br />". "<br />";
}   else    {
    echo "Ligação mal sucedida". "<br />". "<br />";
};
?>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action=""> 
Nomes: 
<select name="candidato"> 
<option value="">Selecione um Nome:</option> 
<?php 
$sql = "select * from candidato";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);
if($resultado)//teste se houve resultado entra no while 
{ 
while($linhas = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){ //monta um vetor colocando todos os resultados em $linhas 
?> 
<option value="<?php $linhas['id_candidato'];//aqui é o valor geralmente se coloca o id da tabela ?>" 
<?php if($linhas['id_candidato'] == $_POST['candidato']){ echo "selected"; /*aqui eu testo e vejo se alguma opção foi selecionada eu a mantenho selecionada*/ }?>
<?php echo $linhas['ca_nome'];} } /*aqui é a parte de exibição a informação que o usuario ira ver na tela "as opções"*/ ?> 
</option> 
</select> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't post your error, please edit the question so we can help.

Comment: the error is in the code

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error and code **as text**. A screenshot of code is not helpful for anyone.

Comment: Is this what do you want ?

Comment: Where is `step` in your code ?

Comment: Step in this `Undefined index: step on line 24`

Comment: Which line nos is 24 ?

Comment: but the error don't have step.

Comment: <?php if($linhas['id_candidato'] == $_POST['candidato']){ echo "selected";

Comment: @PedroLopes "but the error don't have step" - it does. `Undefined index: >>> step <<< on line 24` On line 24 you're trying to use `$array['step']` and step does not exist in `$array`. The code you posted does not have this, so are you sure you've posted the correct file? Look at line 24 for anything refering to `'step'`.

Answer (score 0):

You Missed `>` closing angle bracket. See my answer.

```
<option value="" ></option>
                 ^ You missed this
```

**Updated Answer**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action=""> 
    Nomes: 
    <select name="candidato"> 
        <option value="">Selecione um Nome:</option> 
        <?php 
        $sql = "select * from candidato";
        $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
        if($resultado)
        { 
            while($linhas = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
            ?> 
            <option value="<?php $linhas['id_candidato']; ?>" 
            <?php if($linhas['id_candidato'] == $_POST['candidato']){ echo "selected"; }?> >
                                                                                           ^ Missed > closing angle bracket 
            <?php echo $linhas['ca_nome'];
            } 
        } ?> 
        </option> 
    </select> 
</form>
```

Comment: i try that and continuo with the error

Comment: What error ? @PedroLopes

Comment: the list show me the names of the database but with a error behind.

Notice: Undefined index: candidato in C:\wamp64\www\Trabalho\teste.php on line 24 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0005239632{main}()...\teste.php:0 Paulo Marques

Comment: @PedroLopes Look at your error. `candidato` does not exist. You're using it here: `$_POST['candidato']`. You're most likely not actually posting this value (hence, the index does not exist). Verify what data you're sending with `print_r($_POST)` and you'll realize your mistake. If it isn't nessesarily  available, use `isset()` or `!empty()`.

Comment: thank you @h2ooooooo that help me a lot ;D

Comment: i put <?php if($linhas['id_candidato'] == isset($_POST['candidato'])){echo "selected";}?> and worked

Comment: Ok. Good @PedroLopes. *Keep Coding..!!*

Comment: @PedroLopes That won't work. `isset` will return true or false. You need to use `if (!empty($_POST['candidato']) && $linhas['id_candidato'] == $_POST['candidato'])`.

Comment: but worked now only shows the names in the database of the table candidato